# Using a Wildcard within a level on an MQTT Topic

Tags: mqtt

I want to subscribe to multiple MQTT Topics with slight differences in one of the levels of the topics. For example:

- `sports/tennis/courtA`
- `sports/tennis/courtB`
- `sports/tennis/courtC`

Is there a way to use a single character wildcard?

In all of the searching I've done, I haven't seen anything beyond `#` and `+`. My understanding is that it's not a possibility to publish the letter as a new sub-level (i.e. `sports/tennis/court/A`).

I would like to have something like `sports/tennis/court*`, so I see the court topics, but nothing else in that same level.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can only wildcard at a sub topic level. The only supported wildcards are `#` and `+`

`#` matches 1 or more sub topics but can not be used in the middle of a topic. e.g. `sports/tennis/#` is valid but `sports/#/courtA` is not.

`+` matches a single sub topic and can be placed anywhere in the topic. e.g. `+/tennis/courtA` and `sports/+/courtA` are both valid.

What you could do is subscribe to a wildcarded topic that has a slightly wider scope than you want and then filter again in the message handler since all message handler callbacks should give you access to the incoming messages topic.

e.g. subscribe to `sports/tennis/+` and then filter out anything else that it matches when the message is delivered.

EDIT: sorry I miss a bit in the middle of the question.

`sports/tennis/courts/A` is a perfectly valid topic as is `sports/tennis/courts/B` and would be matched by either `sports/tennis/courts/#` or `sports/tennis/courts/+` (with the understanding that the first would also match `sports/tennis/courts/A/foo` where as the second wouldn't)